# QML Slider value is not updating visually

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a `Slider` in QML. The slider's `maximumValue` property can change depending on certain states in my application. When the `maximumValue` property changes I would like to "reset" my slider so that its `value` property is at the `maximumValue`. The problem what I am encountering is that when I change the `maximumValue` property, my `value` property changes to the right property, but visually it stays at the previous `maximumValue` property until I don't click on the handle for example.

Here is a simple dummy code, which reproduces this issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property int maxVal: 1

    Item {
        width: 20
        height: 200

        Slider {
            anchors.fill: parent

            orientation: Qt.Vertical

            maximumValue: maxVal
            minimumValue: 0
            value: 1
            stepSize: 1.0

            style: SliderStyle {
                groove: Rectangle {
                    width: control.height
                    height: control.width

                    color: "red"
                }

                handle: Rectangle {
                    width: 20
                    height: 20

                    color: "green"

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent

                        text: control.value
                    }
                }
            }

            onMaximumValueChanged: value = maximumValue
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.right: parent.right

        text: "Press Me"

        onClicked: maxVal = 100
    }
}
```

Below you can see some screenshots of certain stages.

When the application opens:
[image: on application start]

When I press the "Press Me" button, which sets the `maximumValue` to 100 from 1. As you can see the `value` did change from 1 to 100, but visually it stayed at the 1 position:
[image: on button press]

Finally when I click on the handler of the slider (green rectangle), then it updates and switches value to 1 from 100.
[image: on slider handle press]

Here is the same thing as a gif:
[image: slider value problem demonstrated visually]

Anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: @derM I am not sure what is the problem on line 45, maybe you made a typo? What do you mean you don't have this issue? If you run my dummy code and you press the button, the green handle stays at the top and says 100 for you? What Qt version are you using? I tried both 5.6.2. and 5.9.2.

Comment: I should say: I thought I can't reproduce your issue. Seems I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [QTBUG-63354](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63354), which will be fixed in Qt 5.9.3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The bug is saying when `maximumValue` is getting set to a smaller value, but actually it happens both directions. Just tried it with my dummy example above...can't believe this honestly...in this month this is my 4th time hitting a Qt/QML bug and have to hack around it somehow...

Comment: If possible I would suggest moving to Qt Quick Controls 2, which is where the active development is.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Qt Quick Controls 2 currently, but thanks for the suggestion.